# How to create layout animation?

Tags: android, android-animation

**I have 4 layout and when i click on blue - other layout must slowly resize, how see in attached images**

[image: **enter image description here**]
The first time I do these things. I would appreciate if someone can help me and give me an example

Comment: Did you try using Scale Animation?